# Magento2: Date Interval Issue in Custom Report

Tags: magento2, database, reports, group

I am creating a custom product viewed report.

I am facing issue in interval column.

Below is my collection

```
$collection = $this->customreportsFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $filterData['from']]);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $filterData['to']]); 
$collection->getSelect()->columns('COUNT(*) as view_times');
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

[image]

Here, If you select period as DAY then data should be only One Date raw and 3 product_name raw in Interval column.

Can anybody please update my collection according.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: My Interval column not working as per Magento Default. What collection I should make so I can get my interval same as Magento. Please check once Magento Product View report and you will get the idea what is my issue.